# Not-null property references a null or transient value on Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm getting a `org.hibernate.PropertyValueException` in Inscrito.postoAtendimento when I'm trying to save an instace of Inscricao.

```
public class Inscricao { 
   ...
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "incCodigo", referencedColumnName = "incCodigo")
   private Inscrito inscrito;
   ...
}


public class Inscrito { 
   ...
   @Column(name = "incPostoAtendimento")
   private Boolean postoAtendimento;
   ...
}
```

However, the property `postoAtendimento` never is null (I'm able to get it on debuger) and I'm not using a bidirectional mapping.

I change my column on database to nullable and the object is save without problem and the value of `incPostoAtendimento` is set to false.

This doesn't make sense to me. Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried making it a primitive boolean?  I seem to recall having problems with Boolean objects, but the memory is hazy.

Comment: Can you show the full code and the stack trace with the offending line?  Haven't had any issues with using Boolean objects.  You can also remove the `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` as that's the default case.